# Shape.OLEFormat and its position in the excel sheet

Tags: excel, vba, checkbox, row, shapes

I wanted to create a simple macro that simply checked if a check box is checked or not and based on that, hide or show the row.

But there are some catches, I cannot link the chackbox to the cell, otherwise another bigger macro generates an error.

I did researcha bit and found that you can do:

```
sheets(1).shapes("Checkbox 88").topleftcell.row
```

to get the row of the shape.

So I tried to implement this to my code:

```
    Dim sh As Shape    
    For Each sh In Sheets(1).Shapes
        If TypeOf sh.OLEFormat.Object Is CheckBox Then
            If sh.OLEFormat.Object.Value = -4146 Then
                'sh.OLEFormat.Object.TopLeftCell.Row.EntireRow.Hidden = True
                MsgBox "Hi"
            End If
        End If
    Next sh
```

I know that the:

```
sh.OLEFormat.Object.TopLeftCell.Row.EntireRow.Hidden = True
```

is wrong, because if I run the macro as I posted it, the macro returns the msgbox "Hi", because the wrong part is commented.

The strange part for me is that if I do:

```
    Dim aux As Byte
    Dim sh As Shape
    
    aux = Sheets(1).Shapes("Checkbox 88").OLEFormat.Object.TopLeftCell.Row
    'checkbox 88 is one of the checkboxes/shapes in the excel document
    MsgBox aux
```

it works to get the row...

I am thinking that the error has to do with the `OLEFormat.object` or something, but my google researches came empty handed.

Comment: Only saying "an error" without specifying the error description and the code line where it is raised, is complete useless... Then, what kind of check boxes do you use? `ActiveX` or `Form` type? Looking to your codes, they look to be of `Form` type. Would be such an assumption a correct one? In order to hide the row, please try: `Sheets(1).Rows(sh.OLEFormat.Object.TopLeftCell.Row).EntireRow.Hidden = True`...

Comment: `sh.TopLeftCell.EntireRow.Hidden = True`

Comment: "I cannot link the checkbox to the cell, otherwise another bigger macro generates an error" - your life would be easier if you fix this problem: then you can reliably associate the checkbox to a specific row.  `TopLeftCell` is not a very robust way to figure out which row belongs to which checkbox.

Comment: Thx, @TimWilliams your first answer works perfectly. The problem of correcting the other macro is that it copies one or multiple rows with checkboxes and paste it in another place, so by copying and pasting the row, the reference stays linked to the one cell from where it was copied from. For example: the  row of "checkbox 88" (row 107) is copied to the row 125, and the CB88 is linked to A107, when the bigger macro copies the row, the CB on the row 125 stays linked to cell A107... that is why I was trying to solve this problem the way I described in this Stackoverflow post.

Answer (score 2):

I would think about ditching checkboxes and replacing them with hyperlinks styled to act like checkboxes.  This allows sorting, copying and pasting, etc with no chance of "drift" where checkboxes can become detached from their assigned row.

Eg: code for creating and supporting links (in a regular module)

```vb
'add some hyperlink "checkboxes" to cell in a range
Sub CreateCheckboxes()
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 1 To 20
        AddCheckBox ActiveSheet.Cells(i, "B")
    Next i
End Sub

'Add a "checkbox" to a cell and do some formatting
Sub AddCheckBox(c As Range)
    With c
        .Hyperlinks.Delete
        .Worksheet.Hyperlinks.Add anchor:=c, Address:="#LinkTarget()", _
                                  TextToDisplay:=UncheckedValue
        .Font.Name = "Wingdings"  'this font has the "checkbox" characters 
        .Font.Size = 12           'remove the default blue+underline formatting
        .Font.Underline = False
        .Font.Color = vbBlack
        .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
    End With
End Sub

'This serves as a "dummy" destination for the hyperlinks
'  Just returns the clicked-on cell, so the selection doesn't jump around
Function LinkTarget() As Range
    Set LinkTarget = Selection
End Function

'Text for a "checked" cell
'Spaces are just to expand the "clickable" area of the hyperlink
Function CheckedValue() As String
    CheckedValue = " " & Chr(120) & " "
End Function
'Text for an "unchecked" cell
Function UncheckedValue() As String
    UncheckedValue = " " & Chr(111) & " "
End Function
'Is a cell "checked"
Function IsChecked(c As Range) As Boolean
    IsChecked = (c.Value = CheckedValue)
End Function
```

Switch link appearance on click (worksheet code module):

```vb
Private Sub Worksheet_FollowHyperlink(ByVal Target As Hyperlink)
    Dim c As Range
    Set c = Target.Range
    
    If c.Column = 2 Then    'if (eg) you need to take some specific action based on where the cell is
        Debug.Print c.Address
        Select Case c.Text  'Toggle cell text
            'You can add code below if some specific action 
            '  to be taken when a checkbox is checked/unchecked.
            'This code just toggles the checkbox appearance
            Case CheckedValue: c.Value = UncheckedValue
            Case UncheckedValue: c.Value = CheckedValue
            Case Else: c.Value = UncheckedValue
        End Select
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Wow, this is very impressive, and way above my current knowledge of VBA, given I just started learning VBA this year basically. I can understand what is happening but I could not think that by myself. Your comments also helped on that. Thank you a lot!