# Excel VBA to add Checkboxes to range - Top location drifts when spreadsheet is on second monitor

Tags: excel, vba, checkbox

I have a simple macro to add a checkbox to each cell in a range, link it to the cell, and (it's supposed to!) position it near the top left of the cell.

```
    Set TargetRange = Worksheets("Sheet 1").Range("Table_1").Columns(5)
    For Each Cell In TargetRange.Cells
        With ActiveSheet.CheckBoxes.Add(Cell.Left, Cell.Top - 1, 24, Cell.Height - 14)
            .LinkedCell = Cell.Address
            .Caption = ""
            .Name = "Checkbox " & Cell.Address
        End With
    Next Cell
```

The first checkboxes look OK, but even after 5 are inserted, you can see the drift:

[image: Checkboxes in cells, aligned with top of cell]

By the time 50 are entered, the checkbox is in the next row down:

[image: Checkboxes in cells, not aligned with top of cell]

Why is Cell.Top not correct after the first checkbox?

I can manually put checkboxes on top of each other, so it's not as if they were getting pushed down by the previous checkbox.

I tried setting the Top location to `Cell.Top - Count`, but that's a bodge, and compressed them too much. I shouldn't have to experiment with scale factors, Cell.Top should do exactly what I need.

**Update:** I am running 3 monitors. I have my VBA window directly in front of me (because that's what I'm working on most of the time), 4K resolution, 150% scaling. I have the spreadsheet on the side monitor, 1080p resolution. If I swap the window positions (i.e. Spreadsheet on the main 4K monitor), it works as expected:

[image]

Sooo.. An annoyance, but not the end of the day. :/

**Update to show result of 150% -> 100% scaling:**
[image]

Comment: Try to set the range hardcoded. For me thats works.

Comment: I tested your code in an table range and it works just fine. I tested it with a table of 300 rows.

Comment: This can be some graphic adapter misfits

Comment: `150% scaling.` That is the issue. Scaling will cause things to drift with VBA and Excel.

Comment: Can I interest you in a different alternative? Which will also not make your workbook heavy and is easy to implement. And ofcourse monitor resolution will not affect it...

Comment: @Andreas - it works when it is on the 150% scaled monitor, not when on the 100% scaled. Setting the main monitor to 100% doesn't affect the outcome (by much) - updated question to show screenshot.

Comment: @SiddharthRout - always open to suggestions, please offer your alternate solution.

Comment: Demonstration using an  [Animated Gif](https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/3xjj57fgxgwqdfjefs7e5/CheckBoxExample.gif?rlkey=8eeq4chlj7p6ba4zr7rsyxkof&dl=0). And this is the [Demo Excel File](https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/ffx0kocpiek8n10drojzv/ScottCheckBoxExample.xlsm?rlkey=alw0bmarnegbkzmgbgi7970sp&dl=0). To check and uncheck the checkbox, simply double click on the yellow cell.

Comment: I just updated the Excel file with Sheet2. That is the 2nd altrnative. You will have to download the file again to see the changes.

Comment: @SiddharthRout - blerg, I'm getting all sorts of Excel security blocks (which I can't bypass because it's a work computer), are you able to post the VBA here please?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256276/discussion-between-siddharth-rout-and-scott).

Comment: To add to Sid's excellent suggestions here's one based on hyperlinks. https://stackoverflow.com/a/75979423/478884  I would avoid creating actual checkboxes because of the exact problem you're asking about.  They don't stay where you put them...

Comment: @Scott it's not the scaling only that is the issue. From what I have understood, it's what monitor the Excel window opened on. Not where it is currently, but where it originally opened. Excel becomes very hard to work with when you are scaling.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your request, I am posting 2 alternatives.

**OPTION 1**

This option uses the `Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick` event. You will have to double click the cell to check/uncheck the boxes.

Let's say you want the checkboxes to be shown in `Range("D2:D10")`. Change the font of this range to `Wingdings 2`

Paste this code in the Sheet code module.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("D2:D10")) Is Nothing Then
        If Target.Value = "£" Then Target.Value = "R" Else Target.Value = "£"
        Cancel = True
    End If
End Sub
```

***In Action***

[image]

**OPTION 2**

This option uses the `Worksheet_SelectionChange` event. You will have to click on the cell to check/uncheck the boxes.

Let's say you want the checkboxes to be shown in `Range("D2:D10")`. Change the font of this range to `Wingdings 2`

In Column E cells, add the formula `=D2="R"`

[image]

Paste this code in the Sheet code module.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Cells.CountLarge > 1 Then Exit Sub

    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("D2:D10")) Is Nothing Then
        If Target.Value = "£" Then Target.Value = "R" Else Target.Value = "£"
        Target.Offset(, 1).Select
    End If
End Sub
```

***In Action***

[image]

[Sample Excel file](https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/ffx0kocpiek8n10drojzv/ScottCheckBoxExample.xlsm?rlkey=alw0bmarnegbkzmgbgi7970sp&dl=0)

**Note**: This is just an example. I have not done any error handling or made it fool proof to handle other scenarios.

Comment: Thanks for the code @Siddharth, interesting implementation. I actually have two columns of checkboxes linked to one column of values - one at each side of a large table. So I'll keep your method in my knowledgebase for potential other uses.

Comment: Sure but you can use this approach instead of using 2 columns of checkboxes as well :)